# Solved - Skins and pgfkeys problems using tcolorbox special features

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, pgfkeys

I'm new to this forum where I have often found useful replies. I hope I'll be accurate enough here.

I've been trying to create a new environment where there would be a left border line and my text besides it. Thus I've been trying to run this code coming directly from the tcolorbox manual :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, external, shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=A working tcolorbox...]
... Where I can write things in it.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=enhanced, blanker, before skip=6pt,after skip=6pt,borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}]
This is an example.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I thought that I found what the problem was when I added `skin=enhanced` in the options of the box, but that do not solve the problem. I still get these errors :

`! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/blanker' and I am going to ignore it.`

And the same for `before skip`, `after skip`, `borderline`. I have looked for it and it is apparently due to some tikz libraries not being correctly loaded, but even when I added `\usetikzlibrary{patterns, external, shadings}` it didn't solve the problem (clearly because `blanker` and `borderline` use another library, yet which one ?

I hope have made myself clear. Thanks for your precious help !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No problem here, so you may want to see whether you can upgrade `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Indeed, "tcolorbox 2014/02/06 version 2.70" appears quite old ! I'm going to look how to update it, I will confirm if it solve my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it was solved by updating software.